# Mysql Values not updating in php pass to html Button

Tags: php, html, mysql, button

In a php file I have:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $mystring=$row['COL 2'];
    echo "<button type=\"button\" id=\"addbutton\" value=\"$mystring\" onclick=\"selectedClasses()\")\">Add Class</button>";
}
```

The values are successfully retrieved and the buttons are successfully created, however, every button ends up containing the value of the first entry.

Is there any way to keep the values updated for each button value?

Comment: *"successfully retrieved"* as in you got data or you got *correct* data. are you sure `COL 2` in your query is actually supposed to be returning different values for each row

Comment: Keep `$mystring` and `echo` both in while loop and try making `$mystring` empty every time before assigning new value to it..  `$mystring = ''` (just a try..) Also make sure that `$row['COL 2']` is returning new value every time, as said  by @Memor-X

Comment: This might be an issue of duplicate `id`s -> `id=\"addbutton\"`. Since all your buttons will have the same `id`, and since `id`s are supposed to be unique, your `selectedClasses()` javascript function is probably just finding the 1st `id="addbutton"` value instead of the button that is clicked.

Comment: Yup if i just echo $row['COL 2'] I get the correct, different-for-each-row data

Comment: Ahhhh the duplicate ids makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

You are putting hard-coded value of button.

Change it to:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $mystring=$row['COL 2'];
    echo '<button type="button" id="addbutton" value="$mystring" onclick="selectedClasses()")>$mystring</button>';
}
```

Buttons have value to be the text between opening and closing tags.

Another thing is the you have made to too much complex double quotes in the statement.

You can simply start and end statement with single quote and use double quotes as much as required.